# Mule Authentication via Spring doesn't return 403

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, mule

I'm trying to create an authentication for a Rest service on Mule 3. If I pass some user/password Spring intercept it and I can authenticate on my java class. However if is passed a wrong user/password and I return null Mule doesn't respond a 403 error. How can I could make it works?

mule xml:

```
<spring:beans>
    <spring:bean class="br.com.arizona.custom_authentication_provider.CustomAuthenticationProvider" id="customAuthenticationProvider"/>
</spring:beans>

<spring:beans>
    <security:authentication-manager alias="secAuthSample">  
        <security:authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider"/> 
    </security:authentication-manager>
</spring:beans>

<spring-security:security-manager>
    <spring-security:delegate-security-provider name="memory-provider" delegate-ref="secAuthSample"/>
</spring-security:security-manager>

<flow name="testFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/teste" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <spring-security:http-security-filter  realm="mule-realm" securityProviders="memory-provider" />
    <response>
       <logger message="response" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </response>
    <logger message="passed" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

CustomAuthenticationProvider.java:

```
package br.com.arizona.custom_authentication_provider;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    String name = authentication.getName();
    String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

    System.out.println(name);
    System.out.println(password);

    if (name.equals("admin") && password.equals("system")) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<>();
        grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
        Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password, grantedAuths);
        return auth;
    } else {
        //throw new BadCredentialsException("Bad Credentials");
        return null;
    }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the security filters: https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Configuring+the+Spring+Security+Manager#ConfiguringtheSpringSecurityManager-SecurityFilters ?

Answer (score 0):

What does it return instead, do you get a 200?

Things depend a bit on the rest of your flow. You could manually check if the authentication was ok, and set the http.status to 403 in the outbound property scope with a message property transformer. Thats normally how you handle your other responsecodes while working with REST.

I assume your authentication mechanism are working, just that the 403 is missing on a incorrect login.